# CMB temperature spectrum

Tags: cosmology, temperature, cosmic-microwave-background

I have read in many references (for instance: http://www.revistacubanadefisica.org/RCFextradata/OldFiles/2019/v36n2/RCF_v36n2_2019_147) that the peaks of the CMB Spectrum is related with the curvature of the universe.
[image]

I would like to know how the peak (a) tell us that our universe is flat, the peak (b) is related with the baryonic matter percentage and peak (c) is related with dark matter percentage.

I am trying to compute the CMB Spectrum and I am basing in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0606683. I am doing the calculation step by step since deriving the boltzmann equation for photons until expanding it in multipoles and I don't see how these results are related with the percentage of the components of the universe. I think I'm missing the physical meaning of the calculation.

Comment: Peak (a) is certainly diagnostic of flatness, but figures 6 and 7 in the paper you refer to, seem too show that your claims about peaks b and c are not correct.

Comment: I would like to know how peak (a) is diagnostic of flatness. About peak (b) and (c) I was based in http://www.revistacubanadefisica.org/RCFextradata/OldFiles/2019/v36n2/RCF_v36n2_2019_147.